# Use VueJs and Typescript without webpack

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to configure a project with minimal configuration. I want to use **VueJS** and **Typescript**.

I add the `vue.js` file and a *script* to my home page :

```
<script src="~/lib/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" ></script>
```

Everything works fine.

But if I want to use **Typescript**, the *Vue* *class* is not found :

```
Symbol 'Vue' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module
```

Because the definitions file uses export, so Vue must be used as a module.

If I add the import, it will compile, but it will be in the output and won't work in the browser.

Is there a way to make this work without using webpack ?

Comment: Why won’t it work in the browser?

Comment: I have an error :
SCRIPT1086: SCRIPT1086: Module import or export statement unexpected here

Comment: I don't think there's a way doing this without a bundler as vue is already pre-packed in your example and therefore most likely not compatible with typescript at that point anyway. I'd highly recommend you use the new vue-cli version 3, as this allows you to setup a typescript vue project with no configuration.

Comment: It seems you're right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typescript types for vue have to be imported by default. You can get them working without import using custom type definition file like this:

Create new file global.d.ts - name does not matter

```js
//global.d.ts
import { VueConstructor } from 'vue'

declare global {
    const Vue: VueConstructor
}
```

Comment: This fails on the `const Vue: VueConstructor` line with `Error TS2403 (TS) Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Vue' must be of type 'typeof import, but here has type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'`